# How to create a roc curve without package in R?

Tags: r, roc

I want to understand the ROC curve. I need to create a ROC curve without using any package in R
I have a dataset with two groups

```
k <- c(rep(0,23), rep(1,23))
x1 <- rnorm(46,0.963,0.26)
x2 <- rnorm(46,-0.006957,0.12)
x3 <- rnorm(46,2.033,1)
df <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, k)
```

I am using linear discriminant analysis to make predictions

```
library(MASS)
md <- lda(k~., data = df)
df$pred <- predict(md, df)$class
```

What I need to do is generating different values of the threshold to identify how the true positive and false-negative change into a ROC curve. This was what I tried to do:

```
true_pos <- (sum(df$k==1 & df$pred==1)-cumsum(df$k==1 & df$pred==1))/sum(df$k==1)
ts <- df$pred == 1 & df$k==1
t_pos <- (sum(ts)-cumsum(ts))/sum(df$k==1)

fs <- df$pred == 1 & df$k == 0
f_pos <- (sum(fs)-cumsum(fs))/sum(df$k==0)

plot(f_pos, t_pos, type = 'l')
```

[image]

This doesn't give me what I need. The above picture is what I want.

Comment: You will never have that curve looking at binary prediction results. You need the, in this case `$posterior`, that's where the useful numbers are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either way, here it is, step by step:

```r
set.seed( 100 )
k <- c(rep(0,23), rep(1,23))
x1 <- rnorm(46,0.963,0.26)
x2 <- rnorm(46,-0.006957,0.12)
x3 <- rnorm(46,2.033,1)
x3[1:23] <- x3[1:23]*0.8 ## give it something to work with!!
df <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, k)

library(MASS)
md <- lda(k~., data = df)
df$pred <- predict(md, df)$posterior[,2]

df.pos <- df %>% filter( k == 1 )
df.neg <- df %>% filter( k == 0 )

fpr <- function( threshold ) {
    sum( df.neg$pred > threshold ) / nrow(df.neg)
}

tpr <- function( threshold ) {
    sum( df.pos$pred > threshold ) / nrow(df.pos)
}

all.predictions <- c( 0, sort( df$pred ), 1 )

perf <- sapply( all.predictions, function(threshold) {
    c( fpr(threshold), tpr(threshold) )
})
perf <- t(perf)

plot( NA, type="n", xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1), xlab="Fpr", ylab="Tpr", main="Manual Labor Builds Character" )
lines( perf )
```

[image]

Comment: This code can certainly be condenced to oblivion, but the point was to take it clearly step by step. Start by looking at the prediction plot( plot true class vs predicted ), and imagine a red line rising up through the plot. For each point it crosses, the Tpr/Fpr combo needs to be calculated.

Comment: What is the paremeter that the ROC curve depends on? What if I want to change the threshold? How should I do it?

Comment: The ROC curve works wtih your _predicted class membership_, the one that hasn't been cut to an integer. It does not look at one single, but _all_ possible threshold values, not a single one. You can take a way two things essentially: The shape of the ROC curve and the area underneath it, AUC. _How_ to set _your_ optimal threshold is a different quiestion entirely. You need to weigh in on that question with what is the most important for you. The ROC curve only shows you, in one aspect, how good your test is compared to other models.

Comment: If you are screening disease for example, you want to be in the lower left corner. You do not want to send someone home with a false negative call. That means the lower left corner is important, proabably sacrificing Tpr to achieve acceptable Fpr.